# C# UWP Two MediaElement at a time

Tags: c#, uwp

I am developing Microsoft UWP . I need a player to play two seperate urls.
MediaElement  has no timeline controle so I create 2 MediaElement and using below code :

```
                            AudioPlayer.AutoPlay = false;
                            AudioPlayer.Source = new Uri("audio url");
                            MediaPlayer.Source = new Uri("video url");
                            MediaPlayer.CurrentStateChanged += (sender, args) =>
                            {
                                AudioPlayer.Position = MediaPlayer.Position;
                                if (MediaPlayer.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Paused)
                                    AudioPlayer.Pause();
                                else if (MediaPlayer.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Playing)
                                    AudioPlayer.Play();
                                else if (MediaPlayer.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Stopped)
                                    AudioPlayer.Stop();
                                else
                                    AudioPlayer.Pause();

                            };
                            MediaPlayer.SeekCompleted += (sender, args) =>
                            {
                                AudioPlayer.Position = MediaPlayer.Position;
                            };
```

How to improve effiency ?

Comment: Check out MediaTimelineController, and helpfully this complete sample for synchronizing media players: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/VideoPlaybackSynchronization

Comment: check thread : "MediaElement has no timeline controler" @JohnnyWestlake

Comment: Do you have any trouble with this scenario? How do you want to improve effiency? By the way, why not use the [MediaPlayerElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaplayerelement)? It has the same functionality as MediaElement, while also enabling more advanced media playback scenarios.

Comment: @OMANSAK MediaElement itself wont, but follow though that sample and read the docs - they don't use MediaElement (which should frankly be deprecated at this point). Use MediaPlayerElement instead as suggested above, and synchronise their MediaPlayers with MediaTimelineController.

Comment: @BreezeLiu-MSFT  MediaPlayerElement have default transport controls ? I have not seen in document

Comment: Both MediaElement and MediaPlayerElement have default transport controls, you can see they by setting the `AreTransportControlsEnabled="True"`.